# Oracle 12c Upgrade from Oracle 10g : The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, oracle12c

I have an C# application which is running fine with Oracle 10g, when i have upgraded to Oracle 12c, application is failing with an error
 *"The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure"*

I have reverted my upgrade the 10g and it was started working fine.please advise, was there any bug/issue in 12c.

Comment: Do you know what stored procedure it's talking about?

Comment: Yes, my code is executing a SP which is working fine when it is connecting to Oracle 10g but not using 12c

Comment: Is it an Oracle SP or a custom SP?  If the former then maybe there's a breaking change.  If the latter then it sounds like some type of bug.  Either way I think you'll need to include the SP and the code used to call it to have any hope of someone answering your question.

Comment: its a custom SP, here is the code for the same. DBCommandWrapper dbCommandWrapper = db.GetStoredProcCommandWrapper (sqlCommand, objVals); 
ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommandWrapper);

Comment: Can you please double check that the number and datatype of the parameters in your actual executing C# code is identical to the number and datatypes in the actual compiled procedure you're calling? If you still have an issue please [edit] your question to include a _minimal_ example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please provide your C# code and the stored procedure.

Comment: what is the oracle error number?

Comment: I found changing from Oracle 10g to Oracle 12c problematic until I changed to the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess client... I saw all sorts of strange things...